# How to call a function using the Visual Studio Code terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have created a python script with a single function in it. Is there a way to call the function from the python terminal to test some arguments?

```py
import time
import random

def string_teletyper(string):
    '''Prints out each character in a string with time delay'''
    for chr in string:
        print(chr, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,2)/20)
```

If I want to test an argument for the function, I would have to add string_teletyper(argument) inside the script itself and run it, is there a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

you can do,

```
>>> from yourfilename import *
>>> string_teletyper(arg)
```

import all function or specific function from the file and you don't need to put `.py` at the end of `yourfilename` when you used it as a module.

Answer (score 0):

Running parts of a Python module many times during development is a common development task. The way most Python developers do this is to use the following code:

```
import time
import random

def string_teletyper(string):
    '''Prints out each character in a string with time delay'''
    for chr in string:
        print(chr, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,2)/20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_st = 'My string to test as an argument'
    string_teletyper(test_st)
```

This means that anything in the if block will only get ran if the module is called via `$python my_file.py` and not called in a module.